# HTML container which expands width with each added child - all in one row?

Tags: html, css

How to force parent to expand with children width.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {

}
.child {
    width: 200em;
    float: left;
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: red;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
background-color: green;
}
```

What I want to achieve:

```
+Parent-----------------+
| child child child ... |
+-----------------------+
```

What I do not want achieve but I am achieving :)

```
+Parent-+
| child |
| child |
| child |
+-------+
```

The best will be if it possible without tables and flex layout - if it possible.

Comment: Are the children elements ever supposed to wrap?

Answer (score 1):

#### Explaination

***I am assuming you DON'T want the child elements to ever wrap.***

First, get rid of `float: left` and replace it with `display: inline-block`.  It achieves the same thing and you aren't taking the element out of the document flow.

Next, on the containing element, `.parent` in this case, add the `white-space: nowrap;` rule.  This will stop the child elements from wrapping around when the viewport width is hit.

#### Final CSS

```
.parent {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.child {
    width: 200em;
    display: inline-block;
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ACsMP/2/)

Comment: Looks like the best - simple and clear - whatever no idea why white-space determine layout and if it valid approach :) Thanks for help I will make some test to confirm.

Comment: @Chameleon `white-space: nowrap` is supported by all major browsers and as far back as IE 5.5.  `white-space: nowrap` tells the browser to ignore line breaks.  When your children elements run out of space, a natural "line break" is implied by the browser so the content wraps.  So now we tell the browser "we don't care if there isn't enough space, just do it!".

Comment: I will soon score you answer I do not forget help.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle example

```
.child {
    width: 100em;
    float: left;
}
```

width is fit to browser when i decrease width its work.

```
.parent {
 display: inline-block;
}
.child {
    width: 10em;
    float: left;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NBdc4/)**

Comment: Good joke - that is not solution :) It must not fit in browser by design.

Comment: `float: left` isn't needed and `display: inline-block` should be used instead. An this doesn't solve the original question per say.